# CreateView is not returning an HttpResponse

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have the following view which extends the base CreateView:

```
class PeopleImportCsv(FailedLoginMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = CsvFile
    form_class = CustomerCsvImportForm
    template_name = 'people/customer_uploadcsv_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        url = reverse('customer_process_csv', args=[self.object.id])
        return url

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.uploaded_by = self.request.user
        super(PeopleImportCsv, self).form_valid(form)
```

I am using the get_success_url() method so I can get the id of the newly created object in the database.  However, when I attempt to submit my form I get the following ValueError message:

```
The view people.views.PeopleImportCsv didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

If I place an `assert False` immediately after assigning the url in get_success_url() then I can see that it has the correct url I'm expecting so what can I do to sort this out?

Comment: You need to have a `return` for the `form_valid` method (if you are using a `ModelForm`): `return super(PeopleImportCsv, self).form_valid(form)`

Comment: @Timmy: Excellent, that's what was missing. Thank you very much.  Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a `return` from the `form_valid` method (if you are using a `ModelForm`):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.uploaded_by = self.request.user
    return super(PeopleImportCsv, self).form_valid(form)
```

You can [see the methods signature in the Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L132)

**P.S** There is a very useful site for referencing Djangos many class based views here: http://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: WHAT AN EXCELLENT LINK! You have any others?

Comment: I found a good site today for django-links in general: http://djangolinks.com/ . You might find more interesting stuff there.